# JSON - Get all matching objects using jq

Tags: json, linux, search, jq

I'm trying to set up automation for an IP address whitelist.

The JSON can be found here: https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com/

I need to generate a list of every "item" in the JSON where "product" contains "bitbucket" (for example).

```
curl https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com/ | jq -c '.items | select(.[].product | contains("bitbucket"))'
```

The output is

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1834): array (["confluenc...) and string ("bitbucket") cannot have their containment checked
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Small sample of the JSON from the URL above:

```
{
  "syncToken": 1644822802,
  "creationDate": "2022-02-14T07:13:22.789203",
  "items": [
    {
      "direction": [
        "ingress",
        "egress"
      ],
      "network": "3.26.128.128",
      "mask_len": 26,
      "region": [
        "ap-southeast-2"
      ],
      "mask": "255.255.255.192",
      "product": [
        "confluence",
        "jira",
        "bitbucket",
        "opsgenie",
        "statuspage",
        "halp",
        "trello"
      ],
      "cidr": "3.26.128.128/26"
    },.........
```

Comment: Try `jq '.items[] | select(.product | contains(["bitbucket"]))'`

Comment: Yes! Thank you that did the trick. I see what I did wrong.

Comment: Thanks to you @pmf I have the following `curl -s https://ip-ranges.atlassian.com/ | jq '.items[] | select(.product | contains(["bitbucket"]))' 2> /dev/null  | jq -cr .cidr` - it could probably be more elegant but gets the job done

Comment: You can combine the two calls into one: `… | jq -r '.items[] | select(.product | contains(["bitbucket"]))? | .cidr'`. Here's a [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/0e9MNwSYp5Z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credit to [pmf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2158479/pmf) for the solution

```
jq -r '.items[] | select(.product | contains(["bitbucket"]))? | .cidr'
```

This worked perfectly